# Cannot call stored procedure from c#

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a working stored procedure in my MySQL database, but when I try to call it from c# I get "No database selected" exception. How do I select the database? (I am a noob)

This is the code I am using in c#:

```
try
{
    string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=mc brown";
    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand("test", conn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
        {
            conn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection string is not correct for MySQL: it should include the database selection, like this:

```
string constring = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Uid=root;Pwd=mc brown;Database=your_database;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I have been struggling with this for a while.
I am very grateful.